# How to convert Set<BookDto> to Set<Book> in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, dto

how can I achieve this? Or should I use directly the book model instead of bookdto for these things? What's the best practice?

[image: Click to see the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot have bean `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

you can just inject it. Better through your component constructor. Or just make an instance.

After that there is two ways. You can map all through stream:

```
   Set<Book> books = bookDtoSet.stream().map(i -> objectMapper.convertValue(i, Book.class)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

or use this approach:

```
   Set<Book> books = objectMapper.convertValue(bookDtoSet, new TypeReference<Set<Book>>() { });
```

It will work in both ways as long as fields are similar by names and types.